# How to make page icon in view pager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have successfully add title but could add icon.Here i am using SectionsPagerAdapter.

I am adding title like this;

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
        return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
        return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

But how to add icon, any idea.

output like this:

```
icon+title   icon+title   icon+title
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which icon want to output with Title Text?

Comment: i have icon in drawable, how to get just before title in title section.